# Jupyter Notebook RISE distorts the HTML/CSS layout of presentation

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, rise

I'm trying to make an entire presentation in Jupyter. I have tried some HTML-CSS in browser first where works almost fine:

**HTML** `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content-wrap">
        <header>
            <h1 id="firstSlideTitle" class="text">This is a long miltiline title for a random topic which nobody cares about!</h1>
            <Lorem></Lorem>
        </header>
        <img src="pics/Python_logo.svg" id="firstSlidePic" alt="PythonLogo" class="center">
    </div>
    <footer>
        <hr>
        <img src="pics/by-nc-nd.svg">
        <p id="twitter" class="text"><a><i class="fa fa-twitter">twitter</i></a></p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

where you can find [the python logo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Python_logo_and_wordmark.svg/2000px-Python_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png) and [the Creative Commons logo](https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/presskit/buttons/88x31/svg/by-nc-sa.eu.svg). and the **CSS** `style.css`:

```
body {
     position: relative;
     min-height: 90vh;
}
 #content-wrap {
     padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
 .text {
     font-family: computer Modern;
}
 #firstSlideTitle {
     width: 80%;
     font-size: 300%;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     margin: auto;
     margin-top: 40px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-radius: 15px;
}
 #firstSlidePic {
     width: 50%;
     height: auto;
     padding: 40px;
}
 .center {
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
}
 footer {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 2.5rem;
}
 #twitter{
     float: right;
     width: 33.3%;
     text-align: right;
}
```

which the result is almost OK:

> [image]

I tried putting the CSS code inside a `<style>...</style>` tag in a code  cell in Jupyter, equipped with `%%html` magic. Also had to change all the `id`s to `classe`s because Python-Jupyter can't handle the `#`s, considering them as python comments. You can find the cell in [this Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/ac6ce69ee88df4a4b088f9df3a91f2f0). However, the result is more of a disappointment:

> [image]

I have tried some workarounds but none of them are good enough. I would appreciate if you could help me know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I did provide some background info on this in the RISE github repo 'Issues' area here
https://github.com/damianavila/RISE/issues/438